# Using "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" within ASP.NET master pages causing new browser to open

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, meta-tags, web-applications, iphone-standalone-web-app

We are trying to create an ASP.NET web app using the "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" meta-tag to control the appearance of the page on an iPad.

It is correctly removing the address bar if I have the URL bookmarked and added to the home screen, but when I navigate from a page that is not using a Master page to a page that is using a Master page, a new browser is opened, and the address bar re-appears on the page that is loaded.  We have narrowed it down to the meta-tag being the common factor, even on pages with no real content and consistent  contents (including the meta-tags).

Has anyone else found a solution to this problem?  We have been unable to find a solution so far through our own work, or searches, and Apple's support site has no answers relating to it.

Comment: Figured I'd answer my own query.  After a lot of reading, it appears that the idea of creating an iPhone/iPad web app that has more than one total HTML page request is simply not an expected use-case.  
Solution? Create the entire web app using Javascript/AJAX interactions with the server, hosted in single page, to ensure the browser chrome remains suppressed.  This has made dealing with Tivoli Access Manager a little more difficult in our current server configuration, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found two solutions to the problem:

- One solution is to make any page requests within the web application using a
  method that is not the standard  link or form submit. 
  This mainly means using javascript such as location.href within user
  controls (links/buttons), or pushing a new page based on an automatic
  server redirect.
- The other is to create the entire web app as a single page download,
  with each individual 'screen' as a separate  displayed and
  hidden as needed.  This is the method that jQuery Mobile uses.

I also established that automated log-in redirects at start-up don't break the web app behaviour, as all the iPhone/iPad web app meta tag settings are stored with the Home Screen icon once that bookmark is created.